# MVC Core : Default Index action not triggered when surfing to "Assets" without specifying "Index"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two URLs, both should resolve to the same page. One doesn't and returns 404

http://localhost:xxx/Assets = 404 not found

http://localhost:xxx/Assets/Index = works as intended

Here's my index action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{

    var vm = new AssetsIndexModel()
        {
          /* snipped, not important */
        };

    return View(vm);
}
```

and this is my only route in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("default", "{Controller}/{Action}/{id?}", defaults: new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });
});
```

This is the only action with this problem. All other actions in the same controller resolve properly. Also, my Home/Index route DOES work if I just surf to "/Home". I can omit "/Index" there, but not in my Assets controller.

Does anyone have any ideas what I may be overlooking?

EDIT:
Also, I create the link to the Index action using the following code

```
<a asp-controller="Assets" asp-action="Index">Manage Assets</a>
```

This produces "/Assets", so MVC seems to understand that it can omit "Index", but then that link just doesn't work and returns 404.

Comment: I found the answer by accident about an half hour later after figuring out some other problem. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer after finding another problem (that at first seemed unrelated).

In my HomeController, an action was added like this:

```
[HttpGet("{assetId}")]
    public IActionResult AssetDetail(Guid assetId)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

This was the problem. I suppose any action anywhere was resolving to this action. Changing the route above to this solved it:

```
[HttpGet("Detail/{assetId}")]
```